# Updating a stackpanel in wpf dynamically doesn't reflect changes in UI

Tags: c#, wpf

Stackpanel in xaml:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="150" Height="280" Name="MyPanel">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Then I add some children to that stackpanel dinamically, for example:

```
MyPanel.Children.Add(new Rectangle { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Chartreuse) }, Width=15, Height=15);
```

I also call `UpdateLayout` from code-behind:

```
MyPanel.UpdateLayout();
```

But the layout remains the same, with only one textbox. I also tried clearing the children beforehand but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Are you setting size to this rectangle that you are adding (width, height)? If not it may not be visible just because of the size. Try to write out in the console count of Mypanel.Children after you add something to it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I left out that part, didn't want to clutter here. Width and height are proportional and should fit. When I examine the count in the console it shows the right number of children, in this case, 2

Comment: I didn't understand your question ? You have to add controls to stackpanel pragmatically ? @Mefhisto1

Comment: Yes, but the changes are not reflected (the rectangle is not shown)

Comment: When are you calling this method `MyPanel.Children.Add(...)`?

Comment: To add another UIElement child to the stackpanel and display it in the window.

Comment: I also trying with your code that working in mine @Mefhisto1

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="500"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo">

    <Grid>
           <StackPanel Name="MyPanel" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {            
        public MainWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                MyPanel.Children.Add(new Rectangle
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 20,
                    StrokeThickness = 1,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                    Margin = new Thickness(5)
                });
            }
        }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would shy away from code-behind logic.

What if you created a rectangle as a DataTemplate within your XAML and then relied on the ItemsSource property of your panel instead to append rectangles?

Through DataBinding, your datatemplate will automatically be mapped for you.